# git installed, but not found during !pip install git+http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git

Tags: python, windows, git, jupyter-notebook

i'm trying to import sklearn.metrics.multilabel_confusion_matrix, but since it is not in the normal package what I'm trying to do is install it using !pip install git+http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git. but when I'm doing this an error is popping up which is shown bellow

I'm pretty sure that i've installed git for my windows and added "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd" to my windows environment path, still no help
so please help me

```
!pip install git+http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
```

```
Collecting git+http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
  Cloning http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git to c:\users\intel\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-637ntld9
  Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-637ntld9
Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?
```

Comment: Does `!git --help` also throw a command-not-found type error? If so, we know it's nothing specific to pip, or to scikit-learn. A good place to start is to look at the current value of `os.environ['PATH']`, and to see if your Git directory is in it.

Comment: Also, which environment are you in where `!foo` runs `foo` at all? That's not true for the standard Python REPL, which implies you're actually running IPython or Jupyter Notebook or something else you aren't telling us about.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, oh i'm sorry bro...i'm using jupyter notebook

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i've added git directory in PATH but when I'm running ```os.environ['PATH']``` as you said, it's not showing the directory which i addded for git..what should i do?

Comment: Hmm. On Windows, I don't have a good answer for you, though if you haven't logged out and back in after changing your PATH settings, I'd suggest doing that now. That said, it's not like you *have* to run the `pip` command from jupyter; you can run it from a terminal/shell window if it's easier to have one with the correct PATH, so long as the `pip` command in use is from the same Python install that Jupyter is using.

Comment: Not to mention installing packages from within a jupyter notebook is generally a bad idea. Set up your environment first, *then* run your jupyter notebook server.